# Pulling out Ticker names from a dataframe, if there are duplicates of Ticker and over a month time difference

Tags: datetime, pandas, group-by

So I have a data-frame `df` that contains a bunch of `Ticker` names, and other columns. 
The index is in datetime form.

It looks something like this:

```
                    Ticker                          Owner  \
SEC Form 4                                                  
1900-10-14 17:15:00     AA                 SORRELL MARTIN   
1900-10-14 17:13:00     AA                     TATA RATAN   
1900-11-07 18:26:00     AA                   NELLES DUANE   
1900-11-10 16:53:00    AAT                  RADY ERNEST S   
1900-11-10 16:53:00    AAT                  RADY ERNEST S   
1900-11-15 17:12:00    ABR                  Tsunis George   
1900-11-15 17:12:00    ABR                  Tsunis George   
1900-11-14 10:02:00    ABT                  WHITE MILES D   
1900-11-14 10:04:00    ABT                  WHITE MILES D   
1900-11-14 10:03:00    ABT                  WHITE MILES D   
1900-11-14 10:02:00    ABT                  WHITE MILES D   
1900-11-14 10:03:00    ABT                  WHITE MILES D   
1900-11-03 14:20:00    AGC                           L.P.   
1900-11-07 14:51:00    AGC               SEIZERT GERALD L   
1900-11-07 14:51:00    AGC               SEIZERT GERALD L   
1900-10-07 17:27:00    AHC            MORONEY JAMES M III   
1900-05-03 18:05:00    AHC            MORONEY JAMES M III   
1900-11-03 18:05:00    AHC            MORONEY JAMES M III
```

I want to print out the Tickers and their accompanying row values( Owner and SEC form  values for those rows), if said Ticker has index dates (SEC Form 4) that are  in different months.  So in this case I want to pull out all the rows with AA, and all the rows with the Ticker AHC as they both contain index dates that are in different months.

So output should be something like this:

```
                   Ticker                          Owner  \
SEC Form 4                                                  
1900-10-14 17:15:00     AA                 SORRELL MARTIN   
1900-10-14 17:13:00     AA                     TATA RATAN   
1900-11-07 18:26:00     AA                   NELLES DUANE   
1900-10-07 17:27:00    AHC            MORONEY JAMES M III   
1900-05-03 18:05:00    AHC            MORONEY JAMES M III   
1900-11-03 18:05:00    AHC            MORONEY JAMES M III
```

I was thinking the best way is to use groupby but I'm not really sure how to proceed from there.

```
 Ticker_groups = df.groupby('Ticker')
```

I was trying to access the index (which holds the dates) but I'm not quite sure how to.

```
 df.groupby('Ticker').index  #doesn't work
```

I looked over the datetimeindex docs and I found

```
DatetimeIndex.month
```

which may be useful but I don't know how to apply it cleanly to the index of the groupby.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `filter` with a lambda function that will do `pd.value_counts` on the month and check if there are more than one entry in there.

```
df.groupby('Owner').filter(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.index.month).shape[0] > 1)

                    Owner           SEC Form 4
Ticker                                        
1900-10-14 17:15:00    AA       SORRELL MARTIN
1900-10-14 17:13:00    AA           TATA RATAN
1900-11-07 18:26:00    AA         NELLES DUANE
1900-10-07 17:27:00   AHC  MORONEY JAMES M III
1900-05-03 18:05:00   AHC  MORONEY JAMES M III
1900-11-03 18:05:00   AHC  MORONEY JAMES M III
```

Comment: Hi, It seems to work perfectly but I'm having a little trouble understanding a part of the code. 
 When I use 'pd.value_counts(x.index.month)'  (with `x' being the groupby object), by itself I get an error. However, if I write the full code you have written, I get no problems. So I'm assuming that's why you are using the filter?  Thanks.

Comment: @moondra, The `groupby` object does not have any data in it. It just stores information about where to partition the dataframe. That's why you get an error there. `groupby` has special functions that do things, `filter` is one of them. You are encouraged to read the [`groupby` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)